# How would you describe the symmetries/group actions on the $\ell_p$ circle?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, metric-spaces, dihedral-groups, noneuclidean-geometry

We define the unit circle as the collection of all vectors with length 1 centered at some point. (The one below specifically defines the unit circle centered at the origin)

$$\mathscr{C} = \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^2 \colon \|\|x\|\| = 1  \}.$$

In this case, the norm used is the Euclidean norm $p = 2$. But we may use the $\ell_p$ metric for $p\in[1,\infty)$ where

$$\|\|x\|\|_p = \left(\|x_1\|^p + \|x_2\|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

We use these metrics to generalize the unit circle as the $\ell_p$ unit circles:

$$\mathscr{C}_p = \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^2 \colon \|\|x\|\|_p = 1 \} .$$

I have depicted some unit circles from $p\in[1,\infty)$.

[[image: <span class=]$\ell_p$ Unit Circles" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C0CF.png)

My question is, what would the group action be on these circles? Of course, the Euclidean circle is part of $O(2)$, but that falters when $p$ deviates from 2 (is this trivial since orthogonal groups preserve the Euclidean norm only?) We see that there are lines of symmetry about $y = 0$, $y=x$, $y=-x$, $x=0$. I'm new to group theory, but would we say that the dihedral group $Dih_4$ *acts* on $\mathscr{C}_p$?

[Richter provides generalized trigonometric functions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X07003538?via%3Dihub) for $\ell_p$ metric spaces. Specifically,

$$\cos_p(\theta) = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{N_p(\theta)}$$

$$\sin_p(\theta) = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{N_p(\theta)}$$

where, $N_p(\theta) = \left(\|\cos(\theta)\|^p + \|\sin(\theta)\|^p\right)^{1/p}.$ These generalized trigonometric functions can also parametrize the curve  of $\mathscr{C}_p$ as $r_p(\theta) = (\cos_p(\theta), \sin_p(\theta))$. Certainly if $N_p(\theta) = 1$, then we have our Euclidean trigonometric functions. I created a contour plot ($p$ vs. $\theta$) for what angles $N_p(\theta) = 1$ is valid below.

[[image: Contour of <span class=]$N_p(\theta) = 1$ for $p$ vs $\theta$ " />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRqX3.png)

The plot roughly shows that when $p\neq2$ this occurs when $\theta \in \{0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2\}$ which conforms with the lines of symmetry above. How do I concretely prove that these are the **only** lines of symmetry and demonstrate/describe the valid group action on $\mathscr{C}_p$?

**EDIT**: I know that my contour plot is also trying to demonstrate that the determinant of this matrix is equal to 1,

$R=\begin{bmatrix}\cos_p(\theta)&-\sin_p(\theta)\\\cos_p(\theta)&\sin_p(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$

or that $R^T = R^{-1}$ iff $\det(R) = 1$.

Comment: This is a very interesting question.

Comment: By "group action" you mean the symmetry group of this unit circle? Are you regarding the circle as a metric subspace inheriting the $l_p$ distance function directly, or as a Finsler submanifold whose distances are measured along the curve of the circle, or are you only looking for isometries of the entire plane with the $l_p$ metric?

Comment: @Magma I am looking for isometries of the entire plane with the $\ell_p$ metric. In this problem, I equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an $\ell_p$ metric where $p\geq1$. And yes, I am looking for the symmetry group of this unit circle.